# Tableau - Conditional Background Color

Tags: charts, colors, tableau-api, categorical-data

I am trying to construct a conditional background, based on a categorical variable, in Tableau.  For example, the fed funds chart; you can see there's a line chart with two background colors.  You can see that the grey extends the entire height of the chart:

http://www.alhambrapartners.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/FED-FUNDS-Rate-1954-to-Present-010612.png

In my data, there are 3 colors.  I can get close to it by using a dual axis chart, but I can't seem to get it just right.  I tried assigning a static variable, and then using the categorical as a color also, however, that doesn't really have the necessary effect.

Does anyone have any ideas?

This is the data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jubue3epaqct0cg/Book3.xlsx?dl=0

This is the Tableau workbook:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/753399kzm922l54/Book5.twbx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...displayed using a count of the categorical, and then a percentage of total.

https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Book5_620/Sheet1?:embed=y&:display_count=no